# Sub-module reference not pushed to remote

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a project which contains 2 git sub-modules. The first I added no problem and I can see a reference to it in my remote repository like so:

[image]

With the second sub-module I followed a similar process:

```
git submodule add <repo_url> <directory_location>
```

The submodule project was successfully added locally. The `.gitmodules` file didn't update automatically so I added the changes myself.

I then used `git add .` and pushed my changes to the remote repository.

When I look at the remote repository there is no reference to the second submodule like there is with the first.

The other thing I noticed is that my `.gitmodules` file isn't updated on my remote repository.

How can I go about debugging this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the problem was completely unrelated to submodules specifically.

I had a `.gitignore` file inside a sub-directory that was referencing folder name like so:

```
puppetdb/
```

As my second sub-module folder shared this same name it caused problems with updating the `.gitmodules` file.

I changed it to read:

```
./puppetdb/
```

Which only referenced the specific instance I intended to ignore.